# What does the norm function do in the notation of a class of convex functions?

Tags: optimization, notation, convex-analysis

In Yurii Nesterov book "Lectures on Convex Optimization" (Springer, second edition, 2018) there are the following definitions of convex and strongly convex functions (def 2.1.2 and def.2.1.3 respectively):

> - A continuously differentiable function $f(\cdot)$ is called *convex* on a convex set $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (**notation $f \in \mathscr{F}^1(Q)$**) if for any $x,y \in Q$ we have
>   $$f(y) \ge f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle.$$
> - A continuously differentiable function $f(\cdot)$ is called *strongly convex* on $Q \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ (**notation $f \in \mathscr{S}^1_\mu(Q,\|\cdot\|)$**) if there exists a constant $\mu \gt 0$ such that for any $x,y \in Q$ we have
>   $$f(y) \ge f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \frac{1}{2} \mu \|y-x\|^2.$$

Everything is clear with these definitions, but on p.74 there is the following statement, which confuses me a lot:

> Note that the class $\mathscr{S}^1_0(Q,\|\cdot\|)$ coincides with $\mathscr{F}^1(Q,\|\cdot\|)$.

**What does the symbol $\|\cdot\|$ mean in the expression $\mathscr{F}^1(Q,\|\cdot\|)$?** As you can see, there is no mention of any norm in the definition of a convex function. So why didn't the author just write $\mathscr{F}^1(Q)$ instead of $\mathscr{F}^1(Q,\|\cdot\|)$? At first I thought that this is just a typo. But then on p.73 I saw the similar expression again: $\displaystyle \min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(x), ~~ f \in \mathscr{F}^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|)$ (again we see this norm symbol)... Do you have any ideas about this?

---

**P.S.** In this book the author often uses the notation $\mathscr{F}^{1,1}_L(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|)$ to denote the class of convex continuously differentiable functions with Lipschitz continuous gradient with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|$. In this class the norm function is used in the definition of Lipschitz continuous gradient, so here everything is clear for me.

Comment: Are there some notion of lower semi-continuity in the book ? We often talk of lower semi-continuous convex functions which is essentially convexity plus some notion of continuity that is related to norm. In any case, you would also have to have l.s.c for the strongly convex functions. I would bet on a change of notation in the middle of the writting of the book that went slightly wrong.

Comment: @P.Quinton, yes, in this book there is definition of a lower semi-continuous function, but only on p.144 (whereas all citations from my post is taken from pages 61 and 74).

Comment: There is not need to put a norm sign into the notation of $\mathcal F$. The statement simply says that a convex function satisfied the inequality appearing for strongly convex functions but with $\mu=0$.

Comment: Since the definition of $\nabla f$ depends on the scalar product considered, I guess that $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ might implicitly mean ``for a given scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and corresponding norm $\Vert x \Vert =  \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}$''.

Comment: @Kas, In the context of convex analysis and optimization I have never seen that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space anyone use some scalar product (i.e. inner product) $\langle x,y \rangle$, which is not equal to the dot product $x^\mathrm{T} y$. We often use different norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but not different scalar products.

Answer (score 1):

*I am writing up the comments in an answer so that this question is marked as answered.*

As mentioned in the comments, the definition on convexity depends on the norm through the scalar product (which appears in the definition of convexity) which induces the norm. If we choose the same norm and $\mu = 0$ in the definition for strong convexity, then we get the convexity definition.